# Como recupera dados digitados no GridView e depois salvar no banco?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gridview

Em uma certa tela de cadastro, tenho um `GridView` com algumas linhas em branco, então o usuário teria que digitar as informações nessas linhas, e então ao clicar no botão salvar, fazer o `INSERT` no banco.

Como faria para quando a célula perder o foco adicionar o valor a um `DataTable`? Sei que existe o evento `LostFocus` mas esse evento é ativado quando o `GridView` perde o focus? Ou quando a célula perde o focus?

Para criar as colunas do `GridView` estou fazendo assim:

```
if (id_crm == 0)
{
   DataTable dat_itens = new DataTable();

    dat_itens.Columns.Add("ITEM", typeof(int));
    dat_itens.Columns.Add("DESCRIÇÃO", typeof(string));
    dat_itens.Columns.Add("DESCRIÇÃO NF", typeof(string));
    dat_itens.Columns.Add("QUANTIDADE", typeof(int));

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        DataRow tablerow = dat_itens.NewRow();
        tablerow["ITEM"] = i;
        dat_itens.Rows.Add(tablerow);
    }

    gridControl1.DataSource = dat_itens;
}
```

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Porque você tem que adicionar o valor a um DataTable?

Comment: Não precisa ser a um datatable, pode ser um list, um dicitionaty, qualquer forma que consiga fazer um insert no banco

Comment: E não pode ser direto do seu grid? As informações estão todas aí em forma de tabela basta você percorrer - lá e recuperar os dados 5

Comment: Hum.. percorro o grid com um data.reader?

Comment: Você pode posta como você esta tentando salva seus dados? a parte que esta no seu botão, e as tabelas que você esta usando. acredito que você tenha uma tabela de CRM e uma de item, poste isso para entender melhor como você poderia fazer. [Essa pergunta tem um exemplo de como você pode percorrer seu grid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271367/read-cell-in-each-row-of-datagridview-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Então, nem comecei ainda a programar o botão de salvar. vou ler essa pergunta que vc me mandou, e hoje tento fazer o botão de salvar, e posto aqui. obrigado.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?

Comment: Perfeito. realmente oque precisava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se sua intenção e recupera os dados para salva em seu banco de dados após o clique no botão salva, você pode simplesmente varrer seu `DataGridView` e recupera campo a campo usando a [Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows(v=vs.110).aspx) Propriedade ele obtém uma coleção que contém todas as linhas de `DataGridView` controle.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in GridItens.Rows)
    {
      var SubCategoriaId = row.Cells["SubCategoriaId"].Value;
      var nomeCat = row.Cells["Nome"].Value;
      var CategoriaId = row.Cells["CategoriaId"].Value;
    }
}
```

Em cada `row.Cells["SubCategoriaId"].Value;` você tem que passa a propriedade name do seu Design conforme a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De resto você precisara abrir sua conexão com o banco com seu insert ou updade e converter os campos para o tipo correto.